# HDMI Splash via Uboot?

Tags: beagleboneblack, u-boot, hdmi

**HW**: BeagleBoneBlack
**OS**: Debian Jessie
**Kernel**: 4.4.30-ti-r64

**U-Boot**:
U-Boot 2016.11-rc3-00002-g73df7f7 (Nov 04 2016 - 15:20:36 -0500)
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc (Linaro GCC 6.1-2016.08) 6.1.1 20160711
GNU ld (Linaro_Binutils-2016.08) 2.27.0.20160829

I've used a UBoot script to do some bit banging to output to an LCD display successfully, but is it possible to actually load an image to an HDMI display via UBoot? Looking around I can't find any good examples of something like this with the Am335x and TDA19988 that the BBB uses, how it is accomplished, or if it's even possible. I have no issue pulling and building from source.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

U-Boot v2019.10-rc2 provides the

```
bmp display <imageAddr> [x y]
```

command to draw a bitmap image that has already been loaded to memory on the display. To enable the command choose

```
CONFIG_VIDEO=y
CONFIG_CMD_BMP=y
```

Instead of the bmp command you can also use CONFIG_VIDEO_LOGO and CONFIG_VIDEO_BMP_LOGO to define a logo to be displayed in the upper left corner of the screen.

As I do not possess a Beaglebone I was not able to test on your hardware.

Comment: Does uboot have native hdmi support? I assumed id have to hack some driver initialization or such to get it to even see the hdmi output

Comment: On my BananaPi I have HDMI output from U-Boot. Same is true for the Wandboard.

Comment: Function void omap3_dss_enable() has a comment /* Enable LCD and DIGITAL OUT in DSS */.